# How to separate each line of text by comma and put them in an array?

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing

I have a text file and I want to create an array out of it like this: `array=["line1","line2",...]`.

Here are the first lines of my text:

```
Hamlet 

William Shakespeare 

Edited Barbara B Mowat Paul Werstine 

Michael Poston Rebecca Niles 

Folger Shakespeare Library 

httpwwwfolgerdigitaltextsorgchapter5playHam 

Created Jul 31 2015 FDT version 092 

Characters Play 

line 17 POLONIUS father Ophelia Laertes councillor King Claudiusthis line substituted  
GHOST
```

And the output should be in the form:

```
lines=["Hamlet"
,"William Shakespeare"
,"Edited Barbara B Mowat Paul Werstine "
,"Michael Poston Rebecca Niles"
,"Folger Shakespeare Library"
,"httpwwwfolgerdigitaltextsorgchapter5playHam"
,"Created Jul 31 2015 FDT version 092"
,"Characters Play"
,"line 17 POLONIUS father Ophelia Laertes councillor King Claudiusthis line substituted","GHOST"]
```

Comment: This question has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988586/creating-an-array-from-a-text-file-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `sed` tool as follows:

```
sed - e '
       s/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//
       s/"/\\"/g;H;$!d;g
        s/\n/","/g;s/.*/"&"/
 ' input
```

When each line iz read in, trim the leading nd trailing whitespace from it.  Escape all double quotes. Append into the hold space and when last line seen, change all newlines to separator of array elements.

Comment: i found it very useful! could you please explain about the code?

Comment: @ Reza, i have added explanations for each sed  command used in a below answer. Please go have a look there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file does not contain blank lines:

```
mapfile -t array <file
```

The `-t` removes the newline from each read line.  This will create the array `array` from the lines in `file` if using `bash`.

It's unclear whether you want the result to be the array itself or the textual representation of the array that you display.

To get the *particular* output that you ask for:

```
mapfile -t array <file
printf '"%s"\n' "${array[@]}" | { mapfile -t arr; IFS=','; printf 'lines=[%s]\n' "${arr[*]}"; }
```

This reads the lines into the array `array` as before.  The next `printf` statement will add double quotes around each element of the array, and send it off to a new `mapfile` command that will read the modified data into a new temporary array `arr`.  This array is used in a `printf` statement that formats its elements in the way that you request, with commas inserted between the double quoted elements.

Using `awk` instead (and not storing the lines in a shell array at all):

```
awk -v OFS=',' '
    { line[NR] = $0 }
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=NR; ++i)
            $i = "\"" line[i] "\""
        printf("lines=[%s]\n", $0);
    }' file
```

This reads each line into an `awk` array.  At the end, double quotes are added to the elements and they are assigned to the output fields (in the `for` loop).  The `printf` statement formats the output in pretty much the same way as in the shell code example.  `$0` represents the current record, whose fields we've just been assigning.

Comment: it's great! there's a minute problem! i want to remove the spaces from both sides of all elements, if it has any. for ex:  "  Michael Poston Rebecca Niles " should turn to "Michael Poston Rebecca Niles", or "Hamlet " to "Hamlet".

Comment: @Reza Pre-process your data to remove the flanking space characters. Passing it through `sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//; s/[[:blank:]]*$//'` would remove any blanks at the start and end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Its really easy to do it via below python script

array = [array.rstrip('\n') for array in open("YourFilename")]

print array

For windows I executed it as below:

C:\Users\XXX>py.exe
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3b436a57, Dec 23 2018, 23:31:17) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > array = [array.rstrip('\n') for array in open("c:/Users/XXX/Documents/sample.txt")]
> > >
> > > print (array)

['Hamlet ', 'William Shakespeare ', 'Edited Barbara B Mowat Paul Werstine ', 'Michael Poston Rebecca Niles ', 'Folger Shakespeare Library ', 'httpwwwfolgerdigitaltextsorgchapter5playHam ', 'Created Jul 31 2015 FDT version 092 ', 'Characters Play ', 'line 17 POLONIUS father Ophelia Laertes councillor King Cl']

> > >

Comment: sorry! it didn't work!!

Comment: What error are you getting? I tried it here and it works perfectly. Hope you are using python script for executing it

Comment: i wrote this script in python 3.6:                                                                                                                  array = [array.rstrip('\n') for array in open("C:\\Users\\Reza\\Downloads\\final_text.txt")]
print (array)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          but nothing happened!

Comment: I executed the same in windows as shown above in answer and it works, I have edited my answer for windows, seems you didn't mentioned the path correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=$'\n'
array=( $(awk '{print "\"" $0 "\""}' input_file) )
```

For **every** line in the `input_file`, from top to bottom, the `awk` command in the command substitution does the following:

1. Surround the line with a pair of double quotes.
2. End the double-quoted line with a newline character.
3. Print the resulting line to the standard output.

**However**, instead of printing to the standard output, the result of the `awk` command is used to replace the entire command substitution. The replacement is the result of the command substitution.

Next, word-splitting is then applied to the result of the command substitution. The word-splitting identifies any sequence of characters not including the `IFS` character but terminated by an `IFS` character to be a distinct "word". Therefore, in this particular case, a "word" is any line (from the `input_file`) that has been enclosed with a pair of double quotes by the `awk` command.

Since the command substitution is enclosed by the outermost pair of parentheses `()`, the result of `awk` is placed in between those parentheses, and the shell treats the entire parentheses including all the substituted tokens in between (which are your lines placed side-by-side each enclosed by a pair of double quotes) as an array.

**NOTE:**

- After the array assignment, you might want to reset the shell variable `IFS` back to its original value of a space, a tab, and a newline.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed - e '
   s/^[[:blank:]]*//;   # trim any leading blanks from the current line read in
   s/[[:blank:]]*$//;   # trim any trailing blanks from the current line read in
   s/"/\\"/g;           # escape any double quotes which might exist in the current line read in
   H;1h;                # append the current line to the hold space, in case of first store as is
   $!d;                 # not yet EOF, drop everything and go back to reading the next line
   g;                   # @ EOF, fetch the hold space: line1\nline2\nline3\n....\nlineEND
   s/\n/","/g;          #  line1","line2","line3","....","lineEND
   s/.*/"&"/;           # "line1","line2","line3","....","lineEND"
' input
```